# Spring behaviour when using interface name also as a bean name?

Tags: java, spring

I found the following unorthodox configuration in my code base the other day and it made me wonder. What is the expected Spring Context behavior when I use an interface name also as the name of a bean? Would it make a difference if I was using @Autowiring in my Controller? The following snippet illustrates this setup:

```
interface MyAppService {...}

class InfrastructureService implements MyAppService {...}

class AdministrationService implements MyAppService {...}

class InfrastructureController {
   // some code
   public void setMyAppService(MyAppService svc){...}
}

<bean id="myAppService" class="InfrastructureService"/>

<bean id="administrationService" class="AdministrationService"/>

<bean id="infrastructureController" class="InfrastructureController">
   <property name="myAppService" ref="myAppService"/>
</bean>
```

Alternatively, what would be the expected behaviour if only the controller was defined as:

```
class InfrastructureController {
   @Autowired
   public void setMyAppService(MyAppService svc){...}
}
```

Comment: Nothing shokes me with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should it matter here? You reference beans by `id` in the xml, not by interface type.

`<property name="myAppService" ref="myAppService"/>`

This means that the property named `myAppService` will have the bean with id `myAppService` injected. Nothing about interfaces.

Edit: If you use autowiring with annotations and you have many different implementations of the same interface registered as components, then you have to use `qualifiers` to tell `Spring` which implementation you gonna use. If you have only one implementation registered, no action is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you put @AutoWired alone it search dependency by Type (In your case it is MyAppService).If you want to narrow down dependecy seaching you can use @Qualifier as below :

```
class InfrastructureController {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("NAME_OF_BEAN")
public void setMyAppService(MyAppService svc){...}
}
```